# creating password protect web service with restler

Tags: php, api, rest, restler

I've successfully developed web service using [restler](http://luracast.com/products/restler/) framework. I can see those methods are accessible if I visit the URL.

But if someone know that URL he can access my data, so my question comes here-

How do I add username/password protected web service using restler?

Comment: you can restrict it using .htaccess.

Comment: Which version of Restler you are using? Restler 2 or Restler 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Restler 3, it's really easy to implement API keys. See:
http://restler3.phpfogapp.com/examples/_005_protected_api/readme.html